# Устаревший метод WithInsecure

Tags: golang

Всем привет.
Есть вот такой код

```
conn, _ := grpc.Dial(":8383", grpc.WithInsecure())
```

Она работает, но висит предупреждение что он устарел и будет поддерживаться только в версиях 1.х и, я так понимаю в версиях 2.х уже не будет поддерживаться.

Вот полный текст  предупреждения

`grpc.WithInsecure is deprecated: use insecure.NewCredentials() instead. Will be supported throughout 1.x.`

Там же в предупреждении сказано что нужно вместо этого использовать insecure.NewCredentials()

Я меняю код до вида

```
conn, _ := grpc.Dial(":8383", insecure.NewCredentials())
```

Но получаю ошибку

`cannot use insecure.NewCredentials() (value of type credentials.TransportCredentials) as grpc.DialOption value in argument to grpc.Dial: missing method apply (compile)`

Как же в таком случае написать правильно, чтобы не использовать устаревший метод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это

```
grpc.WithInsecure()
```

замени на это

```
grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()
```

и все будет ок.

Тебе в ошибке пишут, что нет реализации такого метода:

> credentials.TransportCredentials does not implement grpc.DialOption (missing grpc.apply method)

Answer (score 1):

```
opts = []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials())}
cc, err := grpc.Dial(addr, opts...)
```

вроде NewCredentials может быть изменено или удалено в будущем

Comment: grpc в golang несекьюрные подключения вообще перестанет поддерживать?

Comment: я так не думаю )